# Авторизация в discord

Tags: python, discord

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать. У меня есть дискорд аккаунт и сервер(я не являюсь владельцем в чем и загвоздка), мне надо как- то реализовать, чтобы бот раз в час писал сообщение в определенный канал, но это не проблема. Проблема в том, как мне сделать чтобы в боте как бы был всегда залогинен дискорд аккаунт, чтобы не просило капчу при следующем логине и т.д. Я думал сделать через хромдрайвер, чтобы залогиниться туда и оно так и висело и раз в час отправлялось сообщение, но мне показалось это не рациональным.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду, чтобы бот постоянно активным был?

Comment: Да. Но, я так понимаю, что это возможно реализовать только через селениум, чтобы хромдрайвер был всегда открыт

Comment: А зачем вам постоянно открытый браузер? Просто залейте бота на хостинг

Comment: Вам нужно от своего аккаунта отправлять сообщения?